# R- plot numbers instead of points

Tags: r, plot, scatter

I have successfully made a scatterplot, with different symbols for each data series.  But what I want to do is make the same scatterplot with the point to show up as numbers.  Not the value of each point, just an assigned number.

As of right now, I have three depths I am plotting (0, 3, 6cm).  I have all my 0cm as triangles, etc.  I want my 0cm points to be the character 0, the 3cm points to show up as 3, and the 6cm points to show up as 6.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Sure, just pass the `pch` parameter as a character.

```
dat <- data.frame(x=rnorm(100), y1=rnorm(100)-1, y2=rnorm(100), y3=rnorm(100)+1)
plot(y1 ~ x, data=dat, pch="0", ylim=c(-4, 4))
points(y2 ~ x, data=dat, pch="3")
points(y3 ~ x, data=dat, pch="6")
```

ETA: one nice thing is that the `pch` parameter, like many base graphics parameters, is vectorised. So you can do something like this (which also works for Agstudy's answer).

```
dat <- data.frame(x=rnorm(300), y=rnorm(300) + c(0,3,6), depth=rep(c(0,3,6), 100))
plot(x ~ y, data=dat, pch=as.character(dat$depth))
```

Comment: Note this solution only works for single character labels. For multiple character labels, use `text` as in agstudy's answer.

Answer (score 22):

You can use `text`. Using @HongOoi data:

```
dat <- data.frame(x=rnorm(100), y1=rnorm(100)-1, y2=rnorm(100), y3=rnorm(100)+1)
plot(y1 ~ x, data=dat, type='n', ylim=c(-4, 4))     
text(dat$x,dat$y1,label=0,col='blue')
text(dat$x,dat$y2,label=1,col='green')
text(dat$x,dat$y3,label=2,,col='red')
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `matplot`, which will plot all columns simultaneously.

```
matplot(dat[1], dat[-1], pch = c("0", "3", "6"))
```

[image]

Note that `matplot` defaults to using numbers instead of points (just not the numbers you want in this specific case!):

```
matplot(dat[1], dat[-1])
```

[image]

Data:

```
dat <- data.frame(x = runif(100),
                  y1 = runif(100) - 3,
                  y2 = runif(100),
                  y3 = runif(100) + 3)
```