# adding numbers on the lines of a plot

Tags: r

I am making a plot as follows:

```
plot(df$time,df$response,type='o',ylim=c(2.1,2.8),col='black',xlab='Time (h)',ylab='response(L)')
points(df$time,df$res,type='o',col='black')
points(df$time,df$res,type='o',col='black')
```

here I used `type='o'`to indicate that the lines are with circles at each time point. But I wish to replace the circles with numbers. Like the first line is 1, the second is 2, and the third is 3. Is there a way to realized this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set `pch` equal to the number or use the `text()` function, depending on your needs. You might also look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17859417/r-plot-numbers-instead-of-points).