# Plotting ID numbers instead of points on an r ggplot graph

Tags: r, ggplot2

Hello I would like to basically exactly what this post does [R- plot numbers instead of points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17859417/r-plot-numbers-instead-of-points) 
but in ggplot.

I have a dataframe. I want to plot x and y. Easy. I also have a third column of ID's for all the points. I would like to plot these ID'S from this third column instead of regular points. The IDs are numbers from 1-300.

Comment: Please refer to [How to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 13):

Try this:

```
dat <- data.frame(x=rnorm(300), y=rnorm(300), ID=1:300)

ggplot(dat, aes(x= x, y= y)) +geom_text(aes(label=ID))
```

There are overlapping points and so the IDs overlap on one or the other points.

[image]

Comment: What's wrong in the solution(It's attracting `downvotes`)? Drop a comment, it would help in improving the answer.

Comment: @ChiPak If it was for the same reason as you mentioned, then they do not understand the code.

Comment: you never know when the Internet is concerned. People sometimes don't make sense

Comment: Yes, it won't encourage people to participate in answering the questions.

Comment: On some days, that's SO in a nutshell

Comment: Just upvoted. This is a good solution that addresses OP's request. I don't see why it should attract downvotes either.