# How to display two digit number as points on plot in R?

Tags: r, plot

I am trying to make a scatter plot which uses numbers for each point on the graph, rather than black dots. I can do this for numbers 9 and under, but anything 10 and above is represented by 1 on the resulting plot. The numbers represent individual subjects, and I have 13 of them, with a number of data points from each individual.

I am using the `plot` function for this as I have worked out how to do all the other things I need with that so I am reluctant to change to another plot type/command.

Sample code:

`plot(dif ~ mean, pch=as.character(Subject.Number), data = Cov5.1)`

But `pch=as.character` only works for single digit numbers.
I have seen solutions on here that talk about using text or labels but for whatever I cannot get either of those to work.

Here is one previous question, but the answer doesn't work for me:
[R- plot numbers instead of points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17859417/r-plot-numbers-instead-of-points)

How can I create a scatter plot which uses numbers instead of dots?

Comment: See https://www.r-graph-gallery.com/275-add-text-labels-with-ggplot2/

Comment: Thank you, but I am trying to use the numbers as the actual data points on the plot rather than as labels. Labels will just make it look too cluttered.
In addition I think I will have to start from scratch with all the commands if I use ggplot rather than plot. I have various other lines, labels and titles to put on and I only know how to code for these in plot.

Answer (score 5):

You can do this by displaying the numbers as text, rather than "points".   Just make an empty plot and then add the text.

```
set.seed(1066)
x = runif(13)
y = runif(13)

plot(x,y,type="n")
text(x,y, labels=1:13, cex=0.8)
```

[image: Plotting with numbers]

Comment: Ah ok! So is it the type="n" that tells it to make the plot blank? That's fabulous! Thank you!

Comment: Yes,  type="n"   means set up the plotting area for this data, but do not plot the points.

Comment: I have made this work! For how my data is presented I had to change it to: text(x=Cov5.1$mean, y=Cov5.1$dif,labels=Cov5.1$Subject.Number) otherwise it just seemed to be randomly assigning the numbers 1-13.
Thank you so much! I was getting nowhere and wasting so much time trawling thru stuff online. I am very grateful.